# Question about Erdős–Pósa Proof in Diestel's Graph Theory.

Tags: graph-theory

Diestel's "Graph Theory" provides a proof of the Erdős–Pósa theorem which states:

> There is a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that, given any $k \in N$, every graph contains either $k$ disjoint cycles or a set of at most $f(k)$ vertices meeting
> all its cycles.

The proof starts as follows

> We show the result for $f(k) := \lfloor s_k + k −1\rfloor$. Let $k$ be given, and
> let $G$ be any graph. We may assume that $G$ contains a cycle, and so it
> has a maximal subgraph $H$ in which every vertex has degree $2$ or $3$. Let
> $U$ be its set of degree $3$ vertices.
> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the set of all cycles in $G$ that avoid $U$ and meet $H$ in exactly
> one vertex. Let $Z \subseteq V(H) \setminus U$ be the set of those vertices. For each
> $z \in Z$ pick a cycle $C_z ∈\mathcal{C}$ that meets $H$ in $z$, and put $C' := \{C_z |z \in Z \}$. By the maximality of $H$, the cycles in $C'$ are disjoint.

It does not seem clear to me why the disjointness (or lack thereof) has any thing to do with maximality of $H$. I tried drawing out a simple example, but I am unable to figure out how to add any vertices to $H$ if such a scenario were to happen.

For instance, suppose I find such a cycle $C_z$, that is, a cycle with only one vertex in $H$. It seems to me like I should not be able to ever add it (regardless of what other cycles intersect with it) as $z$ has degree $2$ in $H$. And so, in order to add the cycle to $H$ I would add $2$ to the degree of $z$, but this is impossible.

I suppose it is meant then that one neighboring vertex to $z$ is added to $H$? But then I don't see why two of the cycles cannot intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $C_z$ and $C_w$ (with $z,w \in Z$ and $z \ne w$) are *not* disjoint: they share some vertices, which are necessarily vertices outside $H$.

Follow the cycle $C_z$ (in either direction) until you get to the first vertex that is also on cycle $C_w$. Then follow $C_w$ (in either direction) until you get back to $w$.

If we add this $z-w$ path to $H$, then $z$ and $w$ increase in degree (from $2$ to $3$), and all its internal vertices have degree $2$ (none of the were previously part of $H$). We obtain a graph $H'$ containing $H$ in which all vertices have degree $2$ or $3$. This is the contradiction to the maximality of $H$.